# Cannot extend desktop to 3 monitors

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, thunderbolt

I have an annoying problem. I problem on my old notebook I had a HDMI and VGA port however I could only extend my desktop to one additional screen. I sold that notebook and purchased a new notebook with a DisplayPort 1.2 (Tunderbolt) and miniHDMI.

I purchased this because I was told by Lenovo community that you can have 2 external screens with this notebook.

I purchased: Lenovo ThinkPad S430
- CPU: Intel i5 Quad @ 2.5 Ghz
- RAM: 8GB DDR3
- GPU: Intel HD4000 with nVidia GeForce 620M (Optimus)
- Output:  1x miniHDMI, 1x miniDP (1.2 Tunderbolt)

I plug one screen via HDMI and one via DP to HDMI cable. However I can only extend to one screen at a time. I have all software up to date but cannot extend to 2 additional screens. I went to Intel support page and it shows that the GPU supports desktop extended to 3 screens.

What am I doing wrong here ?

I know that my option is to buy a MST (Multi Stream Hub) that plugs in to DP port and from that I can connect up to 6 screens or something like that but I'm worried now If I order this 200$ very expansive MST Hub if I will be actually able to extend my screen to 2 additional monitors. So Notebooks screen + 2 external screens.

Comment: Try rebooting after you set it up for the third screen. I've seen similar issues many, many times that were resolved after rebooting.

Comment: The thing is I can't activate the 3rd screen the Screen Resolution, Intel and nVidia software all detect it but none can activate it.

Comment: Reboot did not help.

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything online to confirm it not, but I can see it as entirely possible that you may not be able to use the two monitors, and the laptop's LCD at the same time. You may have to turn off the laptop's LCD and extend the displays only onto the two moinitors.

Comment: I've looked all over the Internet and I don't see anything to confirm that you can you use both attached monitors, and the laptop's LCD at the same time, let alone even both of the attached monitors at the same time. You should always be prepared that just because a laptop or graphics card has two monitor ports, doesn't mean you can use both at the same time (especially when they are of a different interface type). Always look for something in the product details that explicity states the option is there.

Comment: If I turn my notebooks LCD off I can extend to both external screens but thats not the point the alternative however is very expansive : P Meaning either USB to DVI which is a tad slow or a MST hub wich is fast but stupidly expansive.

Comment: Its possible you have a defective Intel processor. I'm not sure how you can verify without sending it back to Lenovo.